# JQuery - select entire element except one specific element nested inside

Tags: jquery

is there a possibility to select an element but without one of the elements thats nested inside, if id-s of both elements are known?

like:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div>
        <div id="innerdiv1"> </div>
        <div id="innerdiv2"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to do a select which would return the outerdiv but without innerdiv2 like this:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div>
        <div id="innerdiv1"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there a statement like $('#outerdiv').not('#innerdiv2') or something that would do the trick? 
i can solve this using clone() + remove(), but im just wandering is there a chance to do it this way..

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do this for?

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment. Im trying to serialize the form using $('form').serializeArray(), but want to exclude the inputs from a table which is inside the form element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are,

```
$('#outerdiv div:not(#innerdiv2)')
```

with outer div included:

```
$('#outerdiv div:not(#innerdiv2),#outerdiv')
```

It is actually a valid CSS3 selector, it works in jQuery too.

---

To answer to your comment I've made a little test in browsers console:

```
a = $('<div id="a"><div id="wrap"><div id="one"></div><div id="two"></div></div>')
a.find('div:not(#two)').addClass('a')

Result:

<div id=​"wrap" class=​"a">​
<div id=​"one" class=​"a">​</div>​
<div id=​"two">​</div>​
</div>​
```

The `html()` method prints HTML content of first matched element of the selected stack. Your selected stack looks something like: [#outerdiv, div, #innerdiv1]. So `html()` will show html for of `#outerdiv`. If you need to generate HTML without `#innerdiv2`, then you need to detach it:

```
$('#innerdiv2').detach()
$('#outerdiv').html()
```

Comment: Just a note, this will select all divs within your div that are not `#innerdiv2`. This is INCLUDES the div with no ID (which will still have the `#innerdiv2` in it).

Comment: Thanks guys, but the thing Drackir wrote in parentheses is just the thing im having problems with. I want my alert($('#outerdiv div:not(#innerdiv2),#outerdiv').html()) to show me the structure without the innerdiv2.
)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, all i needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

I thought at first you could do this with selectors, but if you want the html structure, I believe you will need to actually have an html structure, not a list of matching elements by #selector. To wit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clone = $('#outerdiv').clone()
    $(clone).hide();
    $('body').append(clone);
    $(clone).attr('id','cloneddiv');
    $('#' + $(clone).attr('id') + ' #innerdiv2').remove();
    console.log($(clone));
$(clone).remove();
});
```

The console.log() refers to Firebug's console logging tool. This gets what you are looking for, in a way.

I would like to note, someone else had an answer like this, but they deleted it. Not sure why...